# cron job that execute commands remotely via ssh doesn't work

Tags: linux, ssh, cron

I have this test cron job

```
30 15 * * * /usr/bin/sshpass -f /path/to/secret_file ssh -p someport user@host 'ls -la'
```

for my user created via `crontab -e`.
It doesn't work, it does nothing.

If I just run the command it works without problems.
The user that runs the cron job, my user, can read the secret_file.

Why it doesn't work?

Thanks

UPDATE:

using keys and keychain I resolved creating a script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `/usr/bin/keychain --noask --eval id_rsa`
/usr/bin/ssh -p someport user@host 'ls -la'
```

I keep the question open to see if someone know the sshpass way doesn't work.

Comment: Try using -f with the full path to secret_file

Comment: sorry it was not clear but In the real case there is the real path to the secret file. I update the question

Comment: Why not use keys instead of sshpass? Seems much more reliable.

Comment: tried with keys too without the sshpass, but my keys are protected with passphrase and I get `Permission denied, please try again, Permission denied (publickey,password)` even if I use keychain

Comment: Have you read the [CRON log](https://askubuntu.com/a/56811/20358)? Does it give any useful information?

Comment: yes, I see the command executing but no more information neither I get the mail from cron daemon. This is because the command doesn't terminate infact I still see sshpass in the processes list and this is strange